# How to Create route in Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am fresher on zend framework.
I try to create route by

create function "**_initRoutes**" in "**Bootstrap.php**"

```
protected function _initRoutes()
 {
    $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
    include APPLICATION_PATH . "/configs/routes.php";
 }
```

and i create "**routes.php**" in "**application\config\**"

```
$router->addRoute(
  'test',
   new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('test',
    array(
        'controller' => 'TestController',
        'action' => 'test'
   ))
);
```

And I navigate with "**TestController**"

```
 class TestController extends Zend_Controller_Action
 {

   public function init()
   {
      /* Initialize action controller here */
   }

   public function indexAction()
   {
     echo 'TEST INDEX';
   }

   public function test(){
     echo 'ROUTE CALLED';
   }
}
```

If i try the route "**http://localhost:8080/test**",

I receive error message as "**Page Not Found**".

What i do wrong ?

I'm only doing these setups on fresh zend pack.

Is i need to do any thing else for route ?

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: That should be `public function testAction(){}`.

Comment: sorry, Same error.

Comment: try `http://localhost:8080/test/test`.

Comment: Solved, Thank you @

Comment: Try to add your controller's name space, i.e. `'__NAMESPACE__' => 'whatever\it\is', 'controller' => 'TestController',
        'action' => 'test'`

Comment: How to specify namespace,  If i have it in "root/application/controllers/Test/TestController.php" ?

Comment: what's the namespace, defined in your TestController.php? top of the page :) i.e. this is from the default template `namespace Application\Controller;` so it will be `'__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller'`

Comment: OK, Ali Tq.....